# How to use XML documentation files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, xml-documentation

1. When using an external assembly which comes with an XML documentation file, how do I get visual studio to find it?
2. When having an XML documentation file, is there a program or xml transform file or something I can use to look at it in a nice way? Not necessarily as complex as the msdn documentation viewer thingy, but at least something nicer than the pure xml...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1: you simply drop it in the same folder as the dll

2: does it need to be persisted? For "live" use, both the VS IDE and "reflector" allow you to review the documentation (against the types/members/etc). There are tools to transform it, but I've never bothered. [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle/) may be worth a look, but it was never nice to me ;-p

Comment: I tried to drop it in the same folder, but it doesn't want to pick it up it seems. I still get no documentation.

Comment: The files must be Foo.Bar.dll and Foo.Bar.xml (for example); are you sure that you are referencing the dll from that location? And are you sure it is a comments file?

Comment: Seems like I had to restart VS for it to work... is there a command to rebuild/reread documentation or something maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 2: You should be able to look at a "pretty version" of the documentation using the Object browser (View > Object Browser (Ctrl W + J)) and then browse your way to the class for which to review the documentation. I used the Object Browser to review my own documenation since it is more reader friendly than the xml files or the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question: the xml should have the same name as the assembly and be right next to it. So if you have an assembly called Svish.dll then your documentation file should be Svish.xml and be in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

1) The documentation file must have the same name as the assembly name, with the added extension '.xml', and reside in the same directory as its corresponding assembly. So for example, you have an 'MyCompany.MyNamespace.dll' and a 'MyCompany.MyNamespace.dll.xml' file in the same directory.

2) [NDOC](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) can generate some dirrent formats of documentation.

Comment: In the examples I've seen, and that worked for me, it was like in Marc Gravell's answer. That is: `MyCompany.MyNamespace.xml` not `MyCompany.MyNamespace.dll.xml`.