# How to properly add a framework to a project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reference, xml-documentation

I am going to use a framework from codeproject.com, there are a .dll file and .xml file with the package. I added the dll file to my project using `Add Reference...` and browing for it's location. It got added to references, and I can point to it in my code by `using ....`

I have 2 questions:

1. There is a XML file in the package that seems to be comments for methods and stuff like that. how can I use this? (So when I type a method name from that framework its description pop up?)
2. How can I make sure that when building an install for my project, the dll file will be included there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The XML file containing IntelliSense data should be placed in the same location as the DLL you're using.
2. Select the DLL in your ***Solution Explorer*** and open its ***Properties***. Set ***Copy Local*** to ***True***

Comment: Do you mean I have to manually copy both dll and xml file to my reference folder in the project directiory?

Comment: No, just make sure the XML is in the same folder as the DLL you are referencing.

Answer (score 2):

1. After adding a reference to a dll with [xml documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) attached, it will be cached and shown to you by Visual Studio's IntelliSense
2. Set referenced dll property [Copy Local=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx) to make sure it will be always copied to your project output folder

Answer (score 1):

The XML file is documentation file of the dll library. Add reference that dll in your solution with copy local option.

> you simply drop it in the same folder as the dll.

Your question is somewhat same as this one [How to use XML documentation files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665626/how-to-use-xml-documentation-files)